# Projection matrix - how to obtain it

Tags: graphics, 3d, rasterizing

I'm trying to convert from world space coordinates to screen coordinates with a perspective camera. Basically I have this situation:

[image]

where I have the near plane at z=0 and the far plane at z=1, now I'm trying to get x' y' and z' coordinates from x y z coordinates. Since I can use similar triangles properties, I can write

[image]

The red squares are the things I don't understand. How come z' is encoded with such an expression?

And how can the transformation written above be written in the matrix below? I see a z-scale term and a z-translation term but I don't understand them

Comment: Are you familiar with how homogeneous coordinates are used?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection

Comment: Thanks Oli, seems that I am not. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Simply solving the matrix with the link indicated by Oli solves the problem. Sorry for the trouble!